# What is the difference between docker-compose up and docker-compose start?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Whenever I execute

```
docker-compose start 
docker-compose ps
```

I see my containers with the state "UP". If I do

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I will see more verbose but it will have the same state. Is there any difference between both commands?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start

Answer (score 210, accepted):

**docker-compose start**
(https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/start/)

> Starts existing containers for a service.

**docker-compose up**
(https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

> Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.
>
> Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.
>
> The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container
>   (essentially running `docker-compose logs -f`). When the command exits,
>   all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d` starts the
>   containers in the background and leaves them running.
>
> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s
>   configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation,
>   `docker-compose up` picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the
>   containers (preserving mounted volumes). To prevent Compose from
>   picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate` flag.

For the complete CLI reference:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

Comment: updated link to docker-compose CLI reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

* docker-compose up: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

* docker-compose start: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/start/

Answer (score 47):

In docker *[Frequently asked questions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/)* this is explained very clearly:

> **What’s the difference between up, run, and start?**
>
> Typically, you want `docker-compose up`. Use `up` to start or restart
>   all the services defined in a `docker-compose.yml`. In the default
>   “attached” mode, you see all the logs from all the containers. In
>   “detached” mode (`-d`), Compose exits after starting the containers, but
>   the containers continue to run in the background.
>
> The `docker-compose run` command is for running “one-off” or “adhoc”
>   tasks. It requires the service name you want to run and only starts
>   containers for services that the running service depends on. Use `run`
>   to run tests or perform an administrative task such as removing or
>   adding data to a data volume container. The `run` command acts like
>   `docker run -ti` in that it opens an interactive terminal to the
>   container and returns an exit status matching the exit status of the
>   process in the container.
>
> The `docker-compose start` command is useful only to restart containers
>   that were previously created, but were stopped. It never creates new
>   containers.

Comment: how restart command is different from any of these - run , start, up ?

Comment: @Nag `docker compose restart` probably has similar behaviour like `docker restart`. It `stop`s and then `start`s the containers.

Answer (score 10):

#### What is the difference between `up`, `run` and `start` in Docker Compose?

- `docker-compose up`: **Builds**, (re)**creates**, and **starts** containers. It also attaches to containers for a service.
- `docker-compose run`: Run one-off or ad-hoc tasks based on the business requirements. Here, the service name has to be provided and the docker **starts only that specific service** and also the other services to which the target service is dependent (if any). It is helpful **for testing the containers** and also for performing tasks
- `docker-compose start`: **Start the stopped** containers, **can't create new ones**.