# Django - Mysql Database is not created in Docker

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I setup a django project in docker container and every thing is working as expected, except I don't find the project database in mysql image.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir /django-website
WORKDIR /django-website
COPY . /django-website
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=mywebsite
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
            - '33060:3306'
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/mysql
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/django-website
        ports:
            - '8000:8000'
        links:
            - db
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': "django.db.backends.mysql",
        'NAME': "mywebsite",
        'USER': "root",
        'PASSWORD': "root",
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I ran migrate and it worked:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate
```

I createdsuperuser:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py createsuperuser
```

The development server is working `docker-compose up` and the site is working as expected, the issue when I navigate in mysql image I don't find my project related  database which is `mywebsite` .

can you please tell me what is missing? if the database is not created, where has the migration been applied?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, when you "navigate the image"? MySQL databases are not created as files on disk, where are you expecting to see it?

Comment: I know it won't be a file created on the disk. I navigate in mysql image means that I connected to mysql shell in the docker image and used  `SHOW DATABASES`  commands but I didn't find `mywebsite` database. should I find it somewhere else?

Comment: Are you sure you have told Django to use MySQL? Show your DATABASES setting.

Comment: The question has been updated. I am wondering how the migrations been applied correctly and the development server is working without any issue.

Comment: Can you share the results when you ran `docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: @Arihant The result is I mentioned above, the migrations have been successfully applied.

Comment: Where is the `CREATE DATABASE mywebsite`?

Comment: There is already a question raised: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175194/docker-compose-persistent-data-mysql Did you try it?

Comment: @RickJames, actually this is the question, migrations have been successfully applied and the development server is working that means db exists, I logged in **mysql image shell** but didn't find mywebsite database.

Comment: How do "navigate in mysql image" exactly? I spinned up a fresh project with your config files and I manage to connect with Pycharm without any issues. The migrations have been applied and the DB is there.

Comment: @BrunoA. “The DB is there” where exactly? This what I’m looking for, I don’t see any database in MySQL image shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by ***"I logged in mysql image shell but didn't find mywebsite database"***

You are migrated the DB successfully, which means, the DB connections are ***valid*** and *working*.
In your **`docker-compose.yml`** file, the port mapping done like this, **`'33060:3306'`**, which means the **`db`**'s `port 3306`  is mapped to host machine's `port 33060`. So, this ***may be*** the issue (it's not an issue, kind of `typo`)

### How to check the DB contents?

**METHOD-1: check through `django-shell`** of `web` container 
1. run **`docker-compose up`**
2. open a new terminal in the same path and run **`docker ps`**
you'll get something like below

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
795093357f78        django_1_11_web     "python manage.py ru…"   34 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp    django_1_11_web_1
4ae48f291e34        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:33060->3306/tcp   django_1_11_db_1
```

3.Get into the `web` container by **`docker exec -it 795093357f78 bash`** command, where `795093357f78` is the respective container id
4. now you're inside the container. Then, run the command **`python manage.py dbshell`**. Now you will be in ***MYSQL shell of `mywebsite`*** ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRAa7.png))
5. run the command `show tables;`. It will display all the tables inside the `mywebsite` DB

**METHOD-2: check through `db` container** 
1. repeat the steps 1 and 2 in above section
2. get into `db` container by **`docker exec -it 4ae48f291e34 bash`**
3. Now you'll be in bash terminal of MYSQL. Run the following commmand **`mysql -u root -p`** and enter the password when prompt
4. now you're in MYSQL server. run the command, **`show databases;`**. This will show all the databases in the server.

Comment: Thanks @JPG. **I logged in mysql image shell but didn't find mywebsite database** is the same **Get into the web container by docker exec -it 795093357f78 bash**. However, I was able to find the database. In my machine `docker images` shows three results, one of them `mysql:5.7` I got into this container that's why didn't find `mywebsite` database. As I understood, a new container will be created and associated with the project whenever run `docker-compose up`, is that right?

Comment: An instance of an image is called a container.  So whenever run `docker-compose up`  it builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Comment: I think these SO posts will help more :) [What is the difference between a Docker image and a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735149/what-is-the-difference-between-a-docker-image-and-a-container) and [What is the difference between docker-compose up and docker-compose start?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715499/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-up-and-docker-compose-start)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried defining the database image in the dockerfile? The following link is somewhat related to your problem: 
https://medium.com/@lvthillo/customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker-723ffd59d8fb

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this is not the case. mysql image works perfectly and I am able to login in the shell. I was able to create project database manually but unfortunately this database has no tables after performing successful migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that ports value of host container should be 3306 not 33060.
Use docker-compose.yml with value 3306 :

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=mywebsite
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/mysql
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/django-website
        ports:
            - '8000:8000'
        links:
            - db
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the compose specification to `version '2'`. Take down the container and bring it back up with `docker-compose up -d`. Or if you intend to stay with version 3, you can instead use the following specification for database environment parameters

````
```
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mywebsite
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
```
````

When you have problems with containers not coming up, `docker logs <container-name> --tail 25 -f` can give you a lot of information about the cause.